# How to open a partial view by using jquery modal popup in asp.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqmodal

I have a partial view which I want to open by using JQuery Modal Popup. There is no problem while opening the view for a new record but I want to pass data to this partial view for edit. What is your best way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here a neat [article](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-create-a-modal-popup-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-jquery/) for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this working well in my current project.

A partial view uses the **Inherits** control markup just like a full view does to strongly type the Model object to a datatype.

Here is a very simple example of a partial view that is returned via a ajax call and put inside a div.  The purpose of this partialview is to display a text message that is passed through to it.

**LiteralMessage.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<!-- LiteralMessage.ascx start -->
<%= Model %>
<!-- LiteralMessage.ascx end -->
```

**Controller Method**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ReturnId(int id)
{
    return PartialView("LiteralMessage", string.Format("Hello world! Id: {0}", id));
}
```

Note that in the partial page view  can be any complex object.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:** and because this is listed as jQuery as well, use this as your ajax's **success** event. (This is assuming your dialog has a content DIV with an Id of MyDialogMessage inside a dialog DIV with an Id of MyDialog)

```
// executes when $.post is complete
function doSuccess(result)
{
    $('div#MyDialog div#MyDialogMessage').html(result);
    //show dialog
    $('div#MyDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a action on a conroller that returns the [partial view](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/). Then use [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) (via its IFRAME attribute) to load the results of the controller via jQuery.